# Spliting display in half, making two virtual displays

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, multiple-monitors

I would like to split my display in two, so they would behave like two physical monitors, i.e. it would be for example like to connecting two 960x1080 monitors through physical ports. Is something like this possible?

The problem is i would like to run two fullscreen applications on second monitor. Is that even possible? I prefer Windows 7/vista but I welcome Linux solution as well

Comment: Actually Microsoft did something like this for developing countries. Schools would only need one screen for two students. Maybe it can be salvaged somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/). It seems to split the monitor in sections, so it's partly what you're looking for, but I'm not certain if you can run full-screen applications in each portion. Might be worth a look though.